# Deserializing data in custom JsonConverter causing a StackOverflow

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

For a decentralized project I am working on, we needed the ability to pass data between C# applications asynchronously using a Service Bus and decided on JSON (using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library) as the message body format so that we can use other languages in the future without worrying about type differences between languages.

We have a shared library of Interfaces so that both ends are free to handle the messages as they see fit provided they implement the required interfaces. This required a custom `JsonConverter` to handle collections of the interface types, but we didn't want to have to update it every time we added a new Interface type so we wrote a custom serializer that allows for this.

This has been working for over a year now without issue. Last week I made a small change to a different type in the shared library, unrelated to the serializer and converter types, and now every message we try to deserialize results in a **StackOverflow** due to a method call loop (3 methods get called in a loop). Here is the relevant code:

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Custom Converter that allows mapping of interface types to concrete
///     types for deserialization.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     Instead of needing to create multiple JsonConverter classes
///     for each scenario, you can just call the <see cref="AddTypeMapping"/>
///     method to specify a mapping between interface and concrete type.
/// </remarks>
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private Dictionary<string, Type> _map;

    public CustomJsonConverter()
    {
        _map = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds a new interface to concrete type mapping to the converter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="interfaceTypeName">Interface type to create a mapping for.</param>
    /// <param name="concreteType">Concrete type to use for interface type.</param>
    public void AddTypeMapping( string interfaceTypeName, Type concreteType )
    {
        _map.Add( interfaceTypeName, concreteType );
    }

    #region JsonConverter Overrides

    /// <summary>
    ///     Determines if we can successfully convert an object of the
    ///     specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     true if a conversion is possible; false otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        if ( _map.Count == 0 || _map.ContainsKey( objectType.FullName ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     In this case (inside a custom converter), we need to return <c>false</c>
    ///     otherwise we end up in a 'self referencing loop error' when handing
    ///     control back to the default JsonSerializer.
    /// </remarks>
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can read JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can read JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }   // THIS SEEMS TO BE THE ERROR, BUT WHY?
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Parses the supplied JSON data into the proper types, applying conversions where neccessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">JSON data reader instance.</param>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type to convert the JSON data into.</param>
    /// <param name="existingValue"></param>
    /// <param name="serializer">Instance of the serializer to use.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        if ( _map.Count == 0 )
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize( reader, objectType );
        }

        if ( _map.ContainsKey( objectType.FullName ) )
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize( reader, _map[objectType.FullName] );
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException( string.Format( "No mapping for Type '{0}' found.", objectType.FullName ) );
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes the supplied object into the JSON data stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">JSON data writer instance.</param>
    /// <param name="value">Object to serialize into a JSON data stream.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">Instance of the serializer to use.</param>
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        serializer.Serialize( writer, value );
    }

    #endregion
}


/// <summary>
///     Manages the serialization and deserialization of objects to and from JSON.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The object type to be de/serialized.</typeparam>
public class MessageSerializer<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>Serializer instance.</summary>
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    /// <summary>Custome converter instance.</summary>
    private readonly CustomJsonConverter _converter;


    public MessageSerializer()
    {
        _converter = new CustomJsonConverter();

        _serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
        };
        _serializer.Converters.Add( _converter );
        _serializer.Converters.Add( new GuidJsonConverter() );
    }

    #region Converters

    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds a new interface to concrete type mapping in order to allow
    ///     deserialization of JSON data involving an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="interfaceType">The interface type to map to concrete type.</param>
    /// <param name="concreteType">The concrete type to use for the interface.</param>
    public void MapType( Type interfaceType, Type concreteType )
    {
        _converter.AddTypeMapping( interfaceType.FullName, concreteType );
    }

    #endregion

    #region Serialization

    /// <summary>
    ///     Serializes an object to a JSON string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The type to be serialized.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The JSON equivalent of the supplied type.
    /// </returns>
    public string Serialize( T message )
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = null;

        try
        {
            sw = new StringWriter( result );
            using ( var writer = new JsonTextWriter( sw ) )
            {
                _serializer.Serialize( writer, message );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( sw != null )
            {
                sw.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Deserializes a JSON string to it's original type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The JSON string to deserialize.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     Instance of Object Type from the supplied JSON string.
    /// </returns>
    public T Deserialize( string message )
    {
        T obj;
        StringReader sr = null;

        try
        {
            sr = new StringReader( message );
            using ( var reader = new JsonTextReader( sr ) )
            {
                obj = _serializer.Deserialize<T>( reader );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null)
            {
                sr.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    #endregion
}

// SAMPLE USAGE:
var ser = new MessageSerializer<EmailMessage>();
ser.MapType( typeof(IEmailMessage), typeof(EmailMessage) );
var jsonData = ser.Serialize( data );               // works fine
var deserializedData = ser.Deserialize( jsonData ); // StackOverflow occurs during this call
```

The problem seems centered on the `CustomJsonConverter.CanRead` property. This has previously been returning `true` for everything and working fine. Now it will only work if I set it to return `false` (still testing to fully confirm).

The really strange thing is that this property started off returning `false` until almost exactly a year ago when it started failing for no reason until I swapped it to the current value of `true`. Now it seems like I have to switch it back to `false` (until next year)? What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can tell, in the code you have given the `CanRead` property is never used, have you tried just removing this? It probably is not required, especially if it always returns the same value,

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on it in the debugger, it is definitely getting called but the call stack is showing it comes from external code (assuming its the default Newtonsoft JsonSerializer).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be something quite simple... it was all the fault of NuGet! (really mine).

The library for handling messaging with the service bus is built as an internal NuGet package to make it easy for everyone to update when updates become available (and we have had very little changes to this library since it was originally created).

The original messages didn't have any properties that were interface types, so having the `CanRead` property return `false` worked fine and any service handlers used ***version 1*** of the NuGet package. Newer versions of the NuGet package were never needed because the services hadn't changed either.

Newer messages that did have interfaces for properties wouldn't work unless the `CanRead` property returned `true` and any new service handlers that processed those messages happily used ***version 2*** of the NuGet package.

What happened was that we needed to make a change to the core messaging library that would affect **ALL** service handlers so when they got updated to the latest version, the ones that had been using ***version 1*** stopped working. So, I updated the logic of `CanRead` to be as follows and everything is working happily again:

```c#
/// <summary>
///     Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can read JSON.
/// </summary>
/// <value><c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can read JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
public override bool CanRead
{
    get { return _map.Count > 0; }
}
```

It's always something simple...